# Disable Keyboard Shortcuts in Google Search

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to disable keyboard shortcuts in Google Search?

I searched and found solutions to disable it in Gmail, Docs, Drive, etc., but none specific to the Google search page. I also couldn't find them in the search settings.

For example

- When I type `Backspace` I would like navigate back instead of erasing text in the search box.
- I generally use `Search for text when you start typing` feature of Firefox, so when I type I would like to perform search instead of appending the text in the search text box
- Pressing `Escape` should stop loading the page instead of selecting the search box